# Hibernar páginas no Chrome invés de fechar

Tags: windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensão

No Windows podemos invés de desligar podemos mudar para opção de hibernar e assim não precisamos se preocupar em fechar nada pois quando ligar novamente vai estar exatamente na mesma sessão de antes sem erro algum.
Eu gostaria de algo semelhante para o Chrome, que ao invés de fechar as abas elas fossem salvas para ser carregadas direto da memoria do computador invés de baixar novamente da internet. Eu encontrei várias extensões para Chrome mas todas só funcionam manualmente ou dão erro de carregamento da página.
Se o próprio Windows consegue hibernar o Chrome porque não uma extensão ou um software hibernar milhares de páginas do Chrome para poupar tempo e dados de internet.

Comment: http://www.omgchrome.com/how-to-save-tabs-without-installing-extensions/

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/session-buddy/edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko?hl=en

Comment: Para salvar as abas eu indico o Session Buddy e para Hibernar as abas o The Great Suspender, ele suspende toda a comunicação da página, mata todos os processes, porém ele não salva a aba se vc fechar, pra isso uso o Session Buddy